# Extensive survey of computations of equivariant stable stems

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-homotopy

Where  can  I  find  a comprehensive  survey  of  computations  of  equivariant  stems?

To  my  knowledge,  the status  is:

Classical  Work  of Araki  and  Iriye, Osaka  J. Math. 19 (1982). Computations  trough  19th.  stable  stem  for  the  group $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Araki  and  Iriye, Equivariant stable homotopy groups of spheres with involutions. I.
Osaka J. Math. 19 (1982), no. 1, 1–55.  and

Iriye, Kouyemon
Equivariant stable homotopy groups of spheres with involutions. II.
Osaka J. Math. 19 (1982), no. 4, 733–743.

Computation  via  the  Adams  Spectral sequence  for  groups  of  prime  order  trough  degree 2p-2 by  Szymik :

Equivariant stable stems for prime order groups. J. Homotopy Relat. Struct. 2 (2007),

Comparison  to  Motivic  stems  and  use  of  the  Motivic  Adams  Spectral sequence:  by  Dugger,   and  Isaksen.

ℤ/2-equivariant and ℝ-motivic stable stems. 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 145 (2017), no. 8, 3617–3627.

Besides  from the  Tom  Dieck-Segal  Splitting  and  immediate   consequences.

Am  I  missing  something?

Comment: If my search is correct, the last but one title in your list is not exact.

Comment: Thanks  a  lot,  I  edited it. !